# Check if the actual empty System.Object equals empty system.object

Tags: c#, clr

Consider this:

```
var o = new object();
```

How can I check at runtime that `o` is the same as `new object()`.

This failed:

```
  var o = new object();
  var eq1 = o.Equals(new object());
  var eq2 = o.Equals(default(object));
  var eq3 = o == new object();
  var eq4 = Object.Equals(o, new object());
  var eq5 = Object.ReferenceEquals(o, new object());
```

All of the `eq` variables are `false`.

Edit: I was looking to tell that the `o` was `new object` and not, say, re-assigned.
Essentially, checking runtime type is sufficient.

Comment: Did you mean the same object at heap?

Comment: @RodrigodeFarias no I meant that my o variable is exactly the same as `new object()` and has no runtime value.

Comment: @zaitsman: It does have runtime value. Are you thinking of `null` maybe?

Comment: @zaitsman would you mind editing your question so it is somewhat related to accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know two `new object()` are different and only want to check if your object is of type `Object`, you can use [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and check it against [`typeof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx):

```
var o = new object();
bool eq = o.GetType() == typeof(object); // True

int i = new Int32();
bool eq2 = i.GetType() == typeof(object); // False
```

Answer (score 1):

2 different instances of `Object` are always different. There is no .Net comparison that will declare them the same:

- `Object.ReferenceEquals` - 2 new'ed op `Object` will always have different reference identities
- `Object.Equal` defined as reference equality
- `Object operator ==` is also defined as reference equality.

You can't re-define either of `Object.Equals` or `==` as you'd need to derive your class first.

The only cases where comparing values of 2 variables holding `Object` instances will be true are:

- both hold reference to the same instance of an object
- both are `null`

I.e. that this property of `Object` is frequently used for creating unique "lock only" objects to provide private instance of object to `lock` against.